# What's wrong with this simple MySQL syntax? Summing the dates

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

Among the rest, I've got three columns in my table:

`start`- **timestamp**, the default value is `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

`duration`- **datetime**, usually `0000-00-07 00:00:00` (one week)

`end` - **timestamp**, the default value is `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

Here's what I do:

```
UPDATE `banners` SET `end` = `start` + `duration` WHERE `id` = 93
```

No errors appear, the `id` is exact - but the operation doesn't execute, the `end` field just remains at zeros.

What's wrong? Any quotes, brackets needed? I also tried making the middle field the **timestamp** type as well with no result.

Comment: Make the duration an integer that represents day, minutes, seconds, or whatever makes sense for your application.

Answer (score 1):

Very possible, just a little ugly in terms of code...

```
UPDATE `banners`
SET `end` = FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`start`) + (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`duration`) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01 00:00:00')),'%Y-%d-%m %h:%i')
WHERE `id` = 93
```

...you just need to convert everything to seconds, add the duration from teh second one and then convert back to a datetime string for setting :)

Answer (score 0):

If duration is usually 1 week, you can use `DATE_ADD()` function of MySql

```
DATE_ADD(start,INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add `DATETIME` values the same way you add numbers. What's the meaning of `April 25, 2016` added to `January 5, 2016`?

You should store your `duration`s using the smallest time unit that can be used to represent them as integer numbers and use the MySQL [`DATE_ADD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function instead of the addition.

For example, if `duration` is `1 WEEK` then you can use any of:

```
UPDATE `banners` SET `end` = DATE_ADD(`start`, INTERVAL 1 WEEK) WHERE `id` = 93

UPDATE `banners` SET `end` = DATE_ADD(`start`, INTERVAL 7 DAY) WHERE `id` = 93

UPDATE `banners` SET `end` = DATE_ADD(`start`, INTERVAL 168 HOUR) WHERE `id` = 93
```

Comment: you can add DATETIME values after converting them, then you have to convert them back

Comment: @Barry converting them to what?

Comment: convert them to seconds using http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp

Comment: @Barry well, if you convert them to seconds (or anything else) then you don't add dates any more :-)